# Get contents of a table with lxml in python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have this table:

```
<table class='table_small' style='width: 700px;'>
..

 <tr class=''>
                  <td style='text-align: center;'><span class='' style='white-space:nowrap'> 1</span></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>
                      <img src='https://apps.powerplaymanager.com/images/ppm/flags/gab.gif' style='vertical-align: middle;' title='' alt='' />&nbsp;<a href='./news/profile?id=1441'>besser </a>                  </td>
                  <td style='text-align: center;'>8</td>
                  <td style='text-align: center;'><span style='color: #FFFFFF; font-size:14px; text-decoration: none;'></span></td>
                  <td style='text-align: right;' title='Money won in the last 7 days.'>< <span class='' style='white-space:nowrap'>$ 10 000</span></td>
                </tr>


                    <tr class='td_grey'>
                  <td style='text-align: center;'><span class='' style='white-space:nowrap'> 2</span></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>
                      <img src='https://apps.powerplaymanager.com/images/ppm/flags/kna.gif' style='vertical-align: middle;' title='' alt='' />&nbsp;<a href='./news/profile?id=5931'>Kserks </a>                  </td>
                  <td style='text-align: center;'>9</td>
                  <td style='text-align: center;'><span style='color: #FFFFFF; font-size:14px; text-decoration: none;'></span></td>
                  <td style='text-align: right;' title='Money won in the last 7 days.'>< <span class='' style='white-space:nowrap'>$ 10 000</span></td>
                </tr>

.. Keeps going.
```

with this code that I've written:

```
s = generateTree(baseUrl).xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div[8]/div/div[2]/table')[0]

for row in s:
    print([c.text for c in row.getchildren()])
```

Where "generateTree" is a simple wrapper for html.fromstring, to generate a "readable" page for lxml, a tree.

Problem is, with the code, my output is this:

```
[None, None, '\n                      ', '8', None, '$ 10 000']
[None, None, '\n                      ', '9', None, '$ 10 000']
[None, None, '\n                      ', '9', None, '$ 10 000']
[None, None, '\n                      ', '9', None, '$ 10 000']
```

I'd like to get be able to get the contents of each tr class, something like:

```
tr 1[link : www.link.com, level : 3, money : 10,000]
tr 2[link : www.link.com, level : 6, money : 15,000]
..
```

Tried the code above and plenty of xpaths inside that one, but nothing works.

Edit: Pls guys. q.q

Comment: Can this be reproduced without the `generateTree` wrapper? I don't have the source for that so I cannot run your code. Please take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Sure, definitely. Here's my source for the function: http://pastebin.com/N8T7JBMN what this does is take a link (the table that I listed is in there) and do a fromstring, so we can parse with lxml without an issue.

Comment: Please put more effort into providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Edit the question instead of linking to a code snippet in a comment.